# How many plant species and animal species are there in the ocean?

Tags: ocean

For a biology research project I have to look for the estimated amount of plant and animal species in the ocean. After hours of searching, I came here to ask for help. I need both of these questions answered.

1. How many plant species are present in the ocean?
2. How many animal species are present in the ocean?

Comment: http://school.discoveryeducation.com/schooladventures/planetocean/ocean.html is the first thing that came up in google when asking "How many plant and animal species are in the ocean?"

Comment: This is off-topic because 1) it does not appear to be about earth science (but rather biology) and 2) it does not conform to our standards for [homework questions](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/316).